# HTML Input Box custom step buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hope someone can point me in the right direction with this.

I have a simple input box:

```
<form>
<input id="Days" name="Days" type="number" required step="0.025" min="0.000" max="5" value="1.000">
<input type="submit" id="Sub"/>
</form>
```

Which works OK but the users have requested:

- Only allow input in multiples of 0.025
- The up and down arrows move in multiples of 1

So it is perfectly acceptable to type in 1.025 but click on the up arrow in the box gives 1 then 2 etc.

I can configure it to meet either requirement but not both at the same time.  Is there a way to override the behavior of the arrows achieve this?

**Update**

The solution provided by frajk below works well but when you click on submit then you get the message:

[image: The two nearest values are 1 and 2.]

Anyway round that ?

Comment: How about two input boxes.  One steps integer, the other .025

Comment: @joelgoldstick - don't think that would be the sort of user experience they are after.

Comment: try adding `novalidate` to your form tag...example...`<form novalidate>`

Comment: @frajk Ahh yeah that does it,  I did try novalidate on the input field but that doesn't seem to work.   Thanks again,  much appreciated.

Comment: just remember with novalidate, user will be able to submit value larger than 5 or less than 0. you may want to add to the change function in my original answer to check and see if input is above 5 or below 0, and if it is, change value to 5 or 0.

Comment: Oh yeah, spotted that.  Plus issues with other fields that are on the same form that I missed out of the example for clarity.  I've got pretty strong server validation so it may not be a big problem anyway - cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have jQuery available, I think this does what you're looking for

```
<input id="Days" name="Days" type="number" required step="1.000" min="0.000" max="5" value="1.000">

$("#Days").change(function(e) {
    var $ele = $(e.target);
    $ele.val( (Math.ceil($ele.val()*40)/40).toFixed(3) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks,  but I don't think it does.  All that seems to do is give me steps of 0.025 but the up and down arrows still move me in increments of 0.025 not integers.

Comment: @Lobsterpants oops, forgot to change required step. now it should work

Comment: Indeed it does - marvelous.  Thanks for your help, even your mistake helped me understand it :)

Comment: Ahh just found a problem with that,  see the updated question as it all goes wrong when you hit submit.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine as you want in chrome and firefox.
Arrow up click make value change to 1.025.

Comment: But that is not what I want.  Arrow up should change it to 1 (then 2, then 3, etc).

Comment: so, you can use this answer and in place for UP arrow click make the newVal is parsedInt, so there is no numbers after coma.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137111/input-type-number-how-to-check-if-key-up-arrow-or-key-down-arrow-pressedmouse-c#answer-24138044

Comment: OK,  but how does one detect an up arrow click?

Comment: Ok, that answer was not complete, I will think about it.